# Action of a group on itself by conjugation is faithful $\iff$ trivial center

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, intuition

> **Definition 2.15.** A group action of $G$ on $X$ is called *faithful* (or *effective*) if different elements of $G$ act on $X$ in different ways: when $g_1\neq g_2$ in G, there is an $x\in X$ such that $g_1\cdot x \neq g_2\cdot x$.
>
> **Example 2.17.** The action of $G$ on itself by conjugation is faithful if and only if $G$ has a trivial center, because $g_1gg_1^{-1} = g_2gg_2^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$ if and only if $g_2^{-1}g_1$ is in the center of $G$.  When $D_4$ acts on itself by conjugation, the action is not faithful since $r^2$ acts trivially (it is in the center), so $1$ and $r^2$ act in the same way.
>
> *Source*: Keith Conrad, [*Group Actions*](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf).

1. I don't understand how you calculate $g_2^{-1}g_1 \in Z(G)$.  It looks like the author is working with the negation of the definition of faithful?  Then we need to prove: $$g_1 \cdot x = g_2 \cdot x \implies g_1 = g_2.$$

   I understand that because $r^2 = \text{two $90^\circ$ rotations}$, hence $r^2g(r^2)^{-1} = g$ for all $g \in G$.

   The author also presupposes $g = x \in G$. Hence
   $$
   \begin{align}
   g_1 \cdot x = g_2 \cdot x & \iff g_1gg_1^{-1} = g_2gg_2^{-1} \\
     & \iff \color{magenta}{g_2^{-1}}g_1gg_1^{-1} = \color{magenta} {g_2^{-1}}g_2gg_2^{-1} \\
     & \iff \color{magenta}{g_2^{-1}}g_1gg_1^{-1} = gg_2^{-1}.
   \end{align}
   $$

   What now?
2. How do you realize one have to left-multiply by $\color{magenta}{g_2^{-1}}$?
3. What's the intuition?

Comment: Another way to look at this is: The action gives a homomorphism from $G$ to the symmetric group on $X$. The action is faithful iff the kernel of this homomorphism is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding (1.) I understand that left multiplying by $g_2^{-1}$ and right multiplying by $g_1$ gives
$$
g_1 g g_1^{-1} = g_2 g g_2^{-1} \quad \forall g \qquad \rightarrow \qquad 
(g_2^{-1} g_1) g  = g (g_2^{-1} g_1)  \quad \forall g
$$
wich is the definition of $g_2^{-1} g_1$ being in the center of $G$. Then only if the center is trivial, i.e.  $g_2^{-1} g_1= e$ or equivalently $g_1 = g_2$, then the action is faithful.