# When $g\longmapsto \varphi_g: x\longmapsto g^{-1}xg$ a group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $\varphi : G\to Aut(G)$ defined by $$\varphi: g\longmapsto (\varphi_g: x\longmapsto g^{-1}xg)\ \ ? $$

When is $g\longmapsto \varphi_g$ a group homomorphism?

**Attempt**

Let $g,g'\in G$. We have that $$\varphi_{gg'}=\varphi_{g'}\varphi_g,$$
indeed,
$$\varphi_{gg'}(x)=(gg')^{-1}xgg'=g'^{-1}g^{-1}xgg'=g'^{-1}\varphi_g(x)g'=(\varphi_{g'}\varphi_g)(x).$$

so is it a group homomorphism if $Aut(G)$ is commutative ? Because I suppose that if $f(xy)=f(y)f(x)$, it can be seen as a group morphism, no ?

Comment: As I don't have time to post a full answer, here's a (hopefully) useful hint: The automorphisms of the form $x  \mapsto g^{-1}xg$ are known as *inner automorphisms*, and the set of these automorphisms $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is a (normal) subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. It can be shown that $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$. This automorphism, together with the projection $G \to G/Z(G)$ may be useful to you.

Comment: @SteamyRoot: In what your comment is helpful ?

Comment: The whole of $Aut(G)$ need not be commutative in order for $\phi$ to be a morphism, only its image needs to be.

Comment: Incidentally, the failure of this map to be a homomorphism is an excellent reason to denote inner automorphisms using the formula $i_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ rather than $g^{-1}xg$: the first formula does indeed define a homomorhism $G \mapsto \text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher This is entirely convention, in many applications (in fact in almost all of the books / papers I have read) it is more convenient to write $x^g=g^{-1}xg$ so if we, by convention, apply a sequence of automorphisms left first (this is called having automorphisms act on the right, because the map $\phi$ is denoted $x\mapsto x^\phi$ instead of $x\mapsto \phi(x)$), then inner automorphisms are more naturally denoted $x\mapsto x^g$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain: It's not just convention, although I might have made my point more clearly: $g^{-1} x g$ is better for the right action notation which you denoted $x \mapsto x^g$; whereas $g x g^{-1}$ is better for the left action notation which I denoted $i_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$. I guess the convention comes in when different branches of group theory choose left actions and others right actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $G$ abelian if $g \mapsto [x \mapsto g^{-1}xg]$ is a homomorphism $G \to \rm{Aut}(G)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966720/is-g-abelian-if-g-mapsto-x-mapsto-g-1xg-is-a-homomorphism-g-to-rm)

Answer (score 3):

Since $\varphi_{gh}(x) = (gh)^{-1}xgh = h^{-1}g^{-1}xgh = \varphi_h(g^{-1}xg) = \varphi_h(\varphi_g(x)) = \varphi_h \circ\varphi_g(x)$ for an arbitrary $x \in G$, we can conclude that $\varphi_{gh} = \varphi_h \circ\varphi_g$

Now, we have, for arbitrary $g,h \in G$
$$\varphi(gh) = \varphi(g)\circ\varphi(h) $$
$$\iff \varphi_{gh} = \varphi_g  \circ\varphi_h$$
$$\iff\varphi_h \circ \varphi_g = \varphi_g  \circ\varphi_h$$

What do we notice? We must have that if $g,h \in G$, then $\varphi_h \circ \varphi_g = \varphi_g  \circ\varphi_h $, which means that $Inn(G) = Im(\varphi) \leq Aut(G)$ must be an abelian group. This condition is certainly met when $Aut(G)$ is an abelian group, but as you can see weaker conditions can get the job done too.

Comment: No it's not $Aut(G)$ that needs to be abelian, it's merely $Inn(G)$, which is (I think) a much weaker condition

Comment: Yes I did realise this just after I posted the answer. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Changed the downvote into an upvote accordingly :)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate that :)

Comment: Good answer! The condition that $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is abelian is equivalent to $[G,G] \subseteq Z(G)$, in fact.

Comment: Do you have a concret example where it doesn't work ? I can't find any $g\mapsto \varphi_g$ where it doesn't work. thanks.